# Absolute path for pgf externalisation

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files, tikz-external

The graphic externalisation works well when it is done in a subfolder of my TeX files with the command

```
\tikzsetexternalprefix{figures/}
```

However, I get an error message when I try to set a different folder (not a subfolder of my TeX files), such as

```
\tikzsetexternalprefix{H:/figures/}
```

When I compile the document, I only get in the `.log` file (in `H:/figures/BELI.log`) the following error

```
! I can't write on file `H:/figures/BELI.dpth'.
```

Comment: It may be related to the parameter `MIKTEX_ALLOWUNSAFEOUTPUTFILES=1`, but how can I access this parameter, in some .ini file ?

Comment: I use Ubuntu so maybe I'm saying a non-sense... but the correct path is `D://figures/`, isn't it?

Comment: The link `H:/figures/` is correct since LaTeX writes the log file in `H:/figures/BELI.log`

Comment: Did you try to set the `TEXINPUTS` system variable, pointing on the parent directory of `figures/` ?

Comment: @Tarass I get the same error on Windiws 10, how could I set the `TEXINPUTS` system variable?

Comment: @CarLaTeX what LaTeX distribution do you use ?

Comment: @CarLaTeX I know how to do it on texlive, you'll have to adapt it. In `C:\texlive\2016\texmf-dist\web2c` you have to modify a file named `texmf.cnf` transforming `TEXINPUTS.latex         = .;$TEXMF/tex/{latex,generic,}//` in `TEXINPUTS.latex         = .;$TEXMF/tex/{latex,generic,}//;C:/Users/user/BaseFolder//` for each program you use : latex, pdflatex, ... I don't know an other way on windows.

Comment: @Tarass I'll google around and if I don't find anything I'll edit the post or start a bounty, thank you!