# TikZ externalization with absolute path and MiKTeX distribution

Tags: lyx, miktex, tikz-external

This code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix={"C:/Users/MyName MySurname/Documents/LaTeX/Figures/"}] 
%\tikzexternalize[prefix={Figures/}] 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives me the error:

> ! I can't write on file `"C:/Users/MyName
>   MySurname/Documents/LaTeX/Figures/MyMWE-figure0.md5"'.

I'm working with Windows 10, MiKTeX 2.9 distibution.

Following the advice Tarass gave me on a comment of this question: [Absolute path for pgf externalisation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137088/absolute-path-for-pgf-externalisation) and as indicated here: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html I've registered a user-managed TEXMF directory but I still get the same error.

With `\tikzexternalize[prefix={Figures/}]` all works perfectly but, since I'm using LyX, the files are stored in a LyX temp dir, hence I loose them when I close the program (making externalization useless), so I need to use an absolute path.

Comment: Sorry that you seem to be getting less help than you hoped for. Maybe your question is an instance of the XY problem? (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) If this is the case then you might get better answers by telling us your original problem.

Comment: @G.M. Maybe. Should I post another question or edit this one?

Comment: Similar to G.M.'s comment, can you discuss what your end goal is? You can get the PDF file you want, but you also want the individual files that contain the picture's files? Is that right?

Comment: @scottkosty I get the complete PDF file correctly, but I'd like to have the picture's file not delete when I close LyX, otherwise every time I reopen it they are recreated, even if they're not changed. I've written also to lyx-devel: https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-devel@lists.lyx.org/msg195803.html, let me know if this explanation is sufficient or you need more info, thank you!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I see, now I understand. So it is not just a matter of saving them, but you want TikZ to realize that it doesn't have to regenerate them. This is important to know.

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, it is not only save them, I've seen where they are stored and I can retrieve them, the problem is to make LyX use them again, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment in the question you linked too, one can allow miktex to write to absolute pathes by creating the environment variable

```
  MIKTEX_ALLOWUNSAFEOUTPUTFILES
```

and setting it to the value `1`.

Then externalization to an absolute path works fine for me if I avoid to use a path with spaces in it.

**But I don't recommend this**. This is very unsafe, you are allowing miktex to write everywhere and this means it can destroy data in other folders without warnings.

Setting `TEXINPUTS` or creating some local texmf tree is useless -- your problem is about writing not reading.

Comment: But if MIKTEX_ALLOWUNSAFEOUTPUTFILES=1 is not recommended, there is no alternative?

Comment: Ask the lyx support. Or don't use lyx.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer assuming that CarLaTeX is using `-shell-escape` when compiling TikZ, isn't `-shell-escape` a much worse security issue than the one described here?

Comment: @scottkosty, @UlrikeFischer: BTW, I am using `-shell-escape`. I'm accepting the answer to not waste the bounty

Comment: @scottkosty: --shell-escape is a security issue too, and I'm using it with care, but at least normally you can easily enable and disable it. Environment variables have a tendency to get forgotten. Also imho it is much easier to destroy something by accident with the variable, only type once ../ instead of ./ .

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I see, thanks for the explanation. Good point about ../ vs. ./. As for being easy to enable and disable, I'm not sure how it works on Windows, but on Linux it's very common to just enable environment variables for one command, but I don't know if that's how this particular environment variable works (e.g. is it pdflatex that uses the variable or is it some separate MikTeX component?). e.g. I would first try `MIKTEX_ALLOWUNSAFEOUTPUTFILES=1 pdflatex ...` to enable it only for that one pdflatex command.